# How do I print html elements and on textarea using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="(keyC, column) in columns.form" ng-model="columns.form"  >
  <div class="well">
     <p><strong>BLOCK {{ keyC }}</strong></p>
      <div ng-repeat="(keyP, p) in column.perguntas" ng-model="column.perguntas"  >
          <formulario  data="p" ></formulario>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I print html elements and on `textarea` using ng-repeat?
In the end, the html code should be printed inside the `textarea` like this:

```
<div class="well">
   <p><strong>BLOCK 0</strong></p>
   <div class="alert alert-danger">88888</div>         
</div>
<div class="well">
   <p><strong>BLOCK 1</strong></p>
   <div class="alert alert-danger">123123123</div>         
</div>
```

Jsfiddle for a better view of my problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/na4t6k57/

I was trying to do something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
<div ng-init="html = ''"></div>
<div ng-repeat="(keyC, column) in columns.form" ng-model="columns.form"  >
  {{ html += '<div class="well">' }}
    {{ html += '<p><strong>BLOCK' + keyC + '</strong></p>' }} 
      <div ng-repeat="(keyP, p) in column.perguntas" ng-model="column.perguntas"  >
          {{ html += '<formulario  data="p" ></formulario>' }} 
      </div>
  {{ html += '</div>' }}
</div>

<textarea ng-model="html"></textarea>
```

The final result that i want:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/faGfV.png

Comment: "Print" - like print it with a printer or "print" - like render it in your HTML view?

Comment: @lin I just want the html code (who'll be generated) printed on textarea.

Comment: your fiddle seems to do just that ... clarification needed

Comment: Where is your textarea? Cant find it.

Comment: I just want that particular code printed on my textarea for copy http://i.imgur.com/LkRJLOv.png.

Comment: you need to join the text in a function... the foreach doesn't will run your code like a php loop...